# Mapping viewModel object to ICollection entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, automapper-6

I have a basic table with a few FK references. So when I retrieve an entity for an update operation; that entity contains `ICollections` of related entites. My main viewModel contains `Lists` which correspond to these `ICollections`. However, since some other models represent 1-1 mapping, I have `object` instead of `List`. But inside the Entity they continue to be represented as `ICollections`.

This is giving me some problems when trying to map between viewModel and Entity. I am using Automapper for the mapping. I have

```
mapper.Map(viewModel, entity);
```

Currently I am leaving out the problematic models from this mapping and adding them separately. Is there a way to handle everything in one mapping? Is there a way to deal with the ICollections which ideally should be a single object?

**EDIT**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
        public EntityVM1 vm1 { get; set; }        
        public List<EntityVM2> vm2 { get; set; }        
        public List<EntityVM3> vm3 { get; set; }    
}  

public class MainEntity
{
  ... some scalar props...

public virtual ICollection<Entity1> e1 { get; set; }        
public virtual ICollection<Entity2> e2 { get; set; }        
public virtual ICollection<Entity3> e3 { get; set; }        

}
```

Entity1 and EntityVM1 are causing the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the schema your asking about? I've tried to read the question a few times and aren't quite understanding what your asking.

Comment: @JohnMitchell I've added 2 classes.. is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always override the default mapping system in the mapping config of `AutoMapper`, you should have a peek at the [runtime polymorphism in the mapping inheritance](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html#runtime-polymorphism) section of the documentation.

If what you want on the entity is a straight object, why not take Automapper out of the equation and just force EF to map it using a one to one system... i.e

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MainEntity>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Entity1)
        .WithOne(i => i.MainEntity)
        .HasForeignKey<Entity1>(b => b.MainEntityForignKey);
```

HAve a peek at the [EF docs, under section one-to-one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) for more info

Comment: Hi @JohnMitchell , thanks for the reply. In my case either I have to make the viewModel a list or convert it into a list inside the mapping config. But ideally I want the Entity to be regular object instead of ICollection, so that the mapping reflects the relationship. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If what you want on the entity is a straight object, why not take Automapper out of the equation (See edit above)

Comment: Its definitely something that should be fixed at Entity level rather than by Automapper. I'll try changing some constraints on the tables. ( using DB first) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction ;)